# JavaScript Validation in a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to get JavaScript validation in a dropdownlist made in HTML. I have written the following code to try and add validation to a drop down menu in JavaScript, here it is:

```
function validateBasket()
{
if(document.Shopping.elements.Consoles.value == "Please Select")
{
alert("Please select a Console");
document.Shopping.elements.Consoles.focus(); 
return false;
}
}
```

However, when I click the submit button, no validation has been done and it goes straight to the next page. This is the HTML code for the start of the form tag:

```
<form name="Shopping" action="Confirmation_Shop.html" onsubmit="return validateBasket()" method="get">
```

And this is the code for the dropdownlist in HTML:

```
<center><p><b>Select your Gaming Console:</b></p>
<select name="Consoles">
<option value="Default">Please Select</option>
<option value="PS3">PlayStation®3</option>
<option value="XB360">Xbox 360</option>
<option value="PC" >PC</option>
<option value="WII">Wii</option>
<option value="WIIU">Wii U</option>
</select></center>
```

Comment: option's value !== option's text

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 if(document.Shopping.elements.Consoles.value == "Default"){..
```